# Same Data In Multiple Column Or Table

Tags: sql

I have 3 column In  Table 1 in SQL A,B,C and `User_Column` in  `Table 2`.

I want a user who is present in all three column of `Table 1`??? .

Experts please guide me I'm a beginner.

Comment: edit the question add sample data and desired result.

Comment: So all columns, A, B, and C, contain users?

Comment: With SQL questions always tag the DBMS you are using. Which is it? SQL Server or MySQL or Oracle or ...? I've posted a standard SQL solution, which is supported by most DBMS, but not all.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want an intersection of A, B, and C users:

```
select a as usr from table1
intersect
select b as usr from table1
intersect
select c as usr from table1;
```

Comment: No need to check if the user exists in table 2?

Comment: @Jibin Balachandran: No. The task is: "I Want A User who Is Present In all Three Column Of Table 1".

Comment: Then telling about the second table doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Jibin Balachandran: Correct. The request doesn't tell us much anyway. We don't know what table2 represents; we only know it contains a user column. We don't even know whether it's unique (that would make it a user table) or not. It seems not relevant for the task.

Comment: You are right.Since the question doesn't have enough deatils it's difficult to come to a conclusion. +1 from my side